# C++ Visual Studio Express - Assigning return value fails function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having a very odd problem with my program and am hoping you can help. I have a really basic pair of functions. One calls the other and requires a return int.

For reasons completely unknown reasons the first function fails to print out match even though the conditions are true if the return value to a variable is assigned to a variable ie:

Function 1:

```
int function1(int posX, int posY){
    int x=1;
    int y=1;
    if (posX == X && posY == Y){        
        printf("Match");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Function 2:

```
int i = function1(1, 1);
```

Does work:

```
function1(1,1);
```

So to clarify, I'm saying that its working if I get the message "Match".

Comment: There is a `return` inside the `if`. Aren't you missing a `return` outside the `if` (for the false case)?

Comment: If the variables X and Y are declared somewhere else but are still in the scope of this function, you'll be testing those instead. Remember that `X` is not the same as `x`!

Comment: Step through with the debugger to check values, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(posX == X && posY == Y)
```

C/C++ is *case-sensitive*. What do "X" and "Y" stand for?

Maybe try changing them to lowercase?

*Also, always try to `return` a value even if there is NOT a match (the function `function1` is supposed to be returning an `int` value, right?)*

---

**Code :** (corrected)

```
int function1(int posX, int posY){
    int x=1;
    int y=1;

    if ((posX == x) && (posY == y)){     
        printf("Match");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not that, the terms work fine, its only if I assign the return value to a variable that it stops working. Its very odd.

Comment: @EricBanderhide So, I suppose `X` and `Y` are declared elsewhere as global? Anyway, do try putting that `return` statement at the end.

Comment: Thanks Dr Kameleon, it actually turned out to be a really weird error deep deep down the code that was effecting the return. But your answer still taught me a few good points about returns.